# Como hago para imprimir números impares

Tags: c, dev-c++

> Esto es un ejercicio que me mando un profesor que le agregue  que después de sacar el promedio me de los números impares menores al promedio pero el programa coge cualquier numero impar y no los menores y solo uno cuando deberia ser todo los  impares menores al promedio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 30
int main(){
    int n=0,i=0;
    float x[N],suma=0.0,mayor=0.0,menor=0.0,promedio=0.0,impar=0.0;
    do{
        printf("Cuantos numeros desea generar ? ");
        scanf("%i",&n);
    }while(n>N);
    srand(time(NULL));  
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        x[i]=20+(rand()%801)/10.0f;
        suma+=x[i];
        }
    printf("Los %d numeros generados son\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%.2f    ",x[i] );
    }
    mayor=x[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
         if(x[i]>mayor){
        mayor=x[i];
       }
    }
    printf("\nEl numero mayor es %.2f " ,mayor);  
    menor=x[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(x[i]<menor){
           menor=x[i];
        }   
    }
   printf("\nEl numero menor es %.2f",menor);
   promedio=suma/n;
   printf("\nLos numeros mayores al promedio %.2f son\n",promedio);
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      if(x[i]>promedio){
           printf("%.2f   " ,x[i]);
         }
   }
```

> en esta parte lo mas posible es que este mal pero cuando lo cambio ya no sale nada en esa parte  y directamete se termina el programa

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       if(impar=x[i]){    
       impar=(i%2==1);          
       }
    }
    printf("\nLos numeros impares menores son:%.2f",impar); 
   
   
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: tu ultimo if es asi o querias usar un comparador ==  ?. La idea para sacar los numeros impares esta bien dividis entre 2 y si da resto 1 es un numero impar. Pero creo que confundis el signo de asignacion = con el signo de comparacion == eso veo en la ultima parte.

Answer (score 0):

La definición de paridad aplica solamente a números enteros y vos estas usando números con decimal (double) por lo que antes de obtener el resto del numero dividido entre 2, hay que pasarlo a entero con round(), tenés que importar la biblioteca math.h

```
#include <math.h>

printf("\n");
    printf("Numeros impares menores:\n"); 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int redondeo = round(x[i]);
        if(redondeo%2==1 && x[i]<promedio){    
        printf("%i  ",redondeo);        
        }
    }
```

esto imprimirá los números impares menores al promedio (pasados a entero)